# MongoDB add array to BsonDocument

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

I am trying to add fields in a mongodb document using C# drivers.

I am creating a document.

```
BsonDocument document = new BsonDocument();
```

and adding

```
document.Add(name, value); // here name and value both are string
```

but I am not sure how to add an array in this scenario

like `document.Add(name, values); // here values is List<string>`

e.g. `document.Add(skills, [C++, Java, C#]);`

please help me with this

Comment: Did you read this [page](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/)?

Comment: Yes, I have seen this page, but didn't got something direct ..... I am not sure if with some work around I can achieve this ....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're working with a `List<string>`:

```
var skills = new List<string> {"C++", "Java", "C#"};
document.Add("skills", new BsonArray(skills));
```

Or, more simply:

```
document.Add("skills", new BsonArray { "C++", "Java", "C#" } );
```